# Call a function without calling function's wrapper function

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a function:

```
@some_authorization
def to_call():
  pass
```

Now, I want to call this **to_call()** function, but don't want that wrapper function @**some_authorization** get executed. How to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Make 2 different methods.

Comment: `some_authorization` is not performed when you run the function: that is done at interpreter time. It is what is returned by the decorator that each time runs when you call `to_call`.

Comment: Is modifying the decorator an option, or do you have no control over it?

Comment: @Xavi no modifying is not an option. either I need to write the whole to_call function again, or I assume there is some better solution.

Comment: I gave a solution where you only need to wrap the decorator, but not modify any of it's internals. Either that or the other answer is essentially the best you can do in this situation, as far as I know, since there's no guarantee that what's returned by `some_authorization` keeps any accessible reference to `to_call`.

Answer (score 2):

When you decorate a function, you are reassigning its name to whatever is returned by the decorator. If you don't want that, do not decorate the method.

Instead, you can call the decorator as a standard function, passing to it the function, and assign the result to a different name.

```
def some_authorization(f):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        print("authorizing")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return func



def to_call():
    pass

authorized_to_call = some_authorization(to_call)

print('to call')
to_call()
print('authorized to call')
authorized_to_call()
```

(`some_authorization` is the exact same decorator you would use to decorate `to_call` otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

To add to @matszwecja's answer, a decorator need not necessarily return a function (in fact, it need not return anything callable at all, but that'd be a bad idea). So you could return an object that is callable but also allows one to retrieve the original function:

```
def keeping_original_fun(decorator):
    class WrappedFun:
        def __init__(self, fun):
            self.fun = fun
            self.decorated_fun = decorator(fun)
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.decorated_fun(*args, **kwargs)
    return WrappedFun
```

So instead of decorating with some_authorization, you could do

```
@keeping_original_fun(some_authorization)
def to_call():
  pass
```

And this way you can still access the original description of `to_call` through `to_call.fun`.